# I can't open api.github.com on my computer (Laravel installation)

Tags: laravel, connection, connection-timeout

I want to install Laravel with Composer on my computer. Many time tried it but always I'm getting the error message :

> connection failed

After some analysis I found my computer can't connect to `api.github.com`

I can connect `github.com` or another million of websites. But only `api.github.com` is inaccessible.

Chrome says :

> ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

I disabled firewall, closed antivirus, tried to use Cyberghost VPN but unfortunately cant find any solution.

I don't want to install Windows again. it's take too long time for me. Can anyone suggest things for me to solve my problem?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan: thanks for wanting to improve posts here. Please note that product names like Laravel, Windows, Cyberghost are just proper nouns, and so do not need code formatting, since they are not themselves code or console IO. Just getting the case correct is sufficient, thanks.

Comment: Metin, can you `ping api.github.com`? What IP do you get, and do you get replies? What packet loss do you get? Are you on Mac, Windows, *nix?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @halfer ok thank you for helpful notifications.

Comment: @halfer 111.3.3.1 is ping ip. I'm on windows.

Comment: Do you get any packet loss? It should tell you in the ping report.

Comment: What computer name do you get for this endpoint? I am getting a load balancer name of `lb-192-30-253-116-iad.github.com`, so I think it would good to check that you get a name of `lb-xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx-iad.github.com`.

Comment: @halfer I'm getting "Request  timed out"

Comment: What DNS are you using? That's a Chinese IP, [see here](http://whois.domaintools.com/111.3.3.1). I wonder if your provider is monkeying around with your DNS (Great Firewall of China?) or you have a virus that is doing the same. Or perhaps you have modified your `hosts` file? Try this on another computer and/or another connection.

Comment: @halfer I tried to change DNS, disable firewall, disable antivirus but no change. Only api.github.com is inaccessible. This is so weird. I can open github.com. Today i tried on my other laptop and it's installed without any problem. This computer has a problem. Anyway thanks for relations and answers I think i must reinstall windows. Unfortunately.

Comment: Well, I would try another computer and another connection first, to make sure. Good luck!

Comment: Does [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1679326/513903) solve it for you?

Answer (score 0):

If you can't install laravel using composer, simply download the project from https://github.com/laravel/laravel and change rename .env.example file to .env 
and run

```
php artisan key:generate
```

to generate APP_KEY and you all set

Comment: Yes i tried it. but " require(C:\xampp\htdocs\ark/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory" error. vendor directory doesn't exists.

Comment: Run composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog  -inside your project folder

Comment: Yes this is my primary problem :) i can't run this comment because my computer can't connect to api.github.com

Comment: @MetinGenç run composer install - command on the downloaded forlder from github

Comment: Same error." Failed to download symfony/css-selector from dist: The "https://api.github.com/repos/symfony/css-selector/zipball/eac760b414cf1f64362c3dd047b989e4db121332" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream"..  Anyway thanks for relations and answers I think i must reinstall windows. Unfortunately.